# Is a Move any kind of movement, or a specific type of action?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions

The [answer about the Bulette](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138609/49393) brings up an interesting question.

Is *Move* a defined game term?

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your **move** in its space.
>    (Basic Rules p. 74)

It does *not* say you cannot end your turn in a creature's space.
So if you use something other than your *Move*, like an action or bonus action to change positions, can you finish your turn in another creature's space?

Comment: Fyi, markdown doesn't work in titles.

Comment: Your second question is answered here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79816/18221

Answer (score 13):

## *Move* refers to your *movement*

In the PHB (pp. 190-191), this quote:

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space.

appears under the section "Moving Around Other Creatures", which itself is a sub-section under the heading "Movement and Position".

It is arranged this way in [the basic rules on D&DBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures) as well.

The paragraph beforehand also uses *move* in this way:

> You can *move* through a nonhostile creature's space. In contrast, you can *move* through a hostile creature's space only if the creature is at least two sizes larger or smaller than you.

And the sentence after:

> If you leave a hostile creature's reach during your *move*, you provoke an opportunity attack, as explained later in the section

Therefore, the context for this quote is with regards to movement. *Move* is referring to using your movement, not a synonym of "turn".